# Confusion over "Beschäftigung" and "selbständige Tätigkeit" for Blue Card holders

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card, freelance

In the Zusatzblatt of my Blue Card, it is written:

> Beschäftigung nicht gestattet mit Ausnahme der Tätigkeit als Software Engineer bei ABC GmbH, Ort
>
> Selbstständige Tätigkeit gestattet
>
> Nach 2Jähr. Versicherungspfl. Beschäftig. ist Beschäftig. jeder Art gestattet

Now, there is a chance to help out on a university research project as *Wissenschaftliche Hilfskraft* in my spare time, e.g. 40 hours per month.

However, to do that, apparently the university would want me to sign a HiWi contract, as usual.

My understanding is that, I can only work as a *freelancer* (Freiberufler), but not as an *employee* of any other organization. Therefore, I'd need to invoice the university for the services that I perform, instead of being able to sign a normal HiWi contract. I'll also need to register myself at the Finanzamt and get a separate Steuernummer.

Is my understanding correct?

The situation is annoying, since universities here are quite rigid, and it's quite possible that the department wouldn't be able to establish a freelancing working relationship with me due to all the bureaucracy, meaning that I'd miss out on this chance.

Comment: I tried to contact the Ausländerbehörde but apparently they don't have any email or phone, meaning I'd have to go in person to make an inquiry.

Comment: Your understanding is correct and contacting the *Ausländerbehörde* could help a lot. But I doubt they don't have phone or email. You haven't found the contact data yet.

Comment: @Janka I don't think it helps to say things in such certain terms. Why don't you take a look at Berlin ABH's website and tell me where the contact data are, if you're so certain that I "haven't found them"? https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/,  https://www.berlin.de/labo/wir-ueber-uns/artikel.286363.php

Comment: @Janka Apparently they only want to you talk to them over Termine or face-to-face Beratung, since they're overwhelmed or something.

Comment: Well, yes, Berlin. Our failed state.

Comment: They have a contact form. Klick *Kontakt* on the top of the page you linked. Click on *Fragen zu Aufenthalt, Einreise, etc.→Weitere Informationen*. Click on *B 2 – Studium, Wissenschaft und andere besondere Aufenthaltszwecke*.

Comment: @Janka Thanks. Didn't find that. Let me see if they offer a reply soon...